# how do i access a public method of a default class outside the package

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class with no modifier(default), which has a public method called mymeth. I know I could access the method when I am within the package. However I would like to access the method when I am outside the package. does anyone has an Idea on how it could be done. theoretically I think it should be possible since public method means access by the world. here is the example of my class and method:

```
class myclass{

public void mymeth(int i,int b){

.....
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface SomeInterface{
   public void mymeth();
}

class MyClass implements SomeInterface{

   public void mymeth(){

   }
}

//is in the same package as MyClass
public MyClassFactory{
   public SomeInterface create(/*parameters*/){
       //create instance from parameters
       //For your case
       MyClass instanceOfAnyClassThatImplementsSomeInterface = new MyClass(/*pass the parameters*/); 
       return instanceOfAnyClassThatImplementsSomeInterface;
   }
}
```

One of the ways is already defined in answers but If you want to restrict the public access of the class then you can create an interface and access the method through it.

Comment: Can you show please how could you access and initialize non-public class from different package with interface? your answer is not clear. Thank you

Comment: @MaximShoustin The question does not discuss how to create instances of such class but about accessing the public method of default modifier class. For your purposes there can be a factory in the same package that returns the concrete instance of MyClass which implements SomeInterface and so you can access the method. The answer to that can be too broad.

Comment: @NarendraPathai I tried to implement the interface , however I met the initialization problem.. how could i initialize the class with the interface given the fact that the conctructor takes some parameters.. for example the constructor looks like : public MyClass(int i,int b ){ ...}

Comment: @eskoba I have added the answer to that check it out.

Answer (score 1):

set `myclass` class to be `public`.

**FYI, Classes in Java start from upper Case letter

Comment: First thank you for your answer.. HoweverI know that if I set my class to public it will work fine but for security reasons I do not want to set it to public

Comment: For that reason you must use `Interface` instead to open only specific API. This is what most companies do. I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Directly you cannot. 'public' makes everything visible. But if you can't see the class, it's difficult to call anything. However,

You can extend the default class with a public class, eventually myMeth is exposed.

PubClass.java

```
package p1;

class DefClass{
    public void myMeth(){
        System.out.println("from myMeth!");
    }
}

public class PubClass extends DefClass{
    public PubClass(){
        super();
    }
}
```

MainClass.java

```
package p2;

class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        p1.PubClass pub = new p1.PubClass();

        pub.myMeth();
    }

}
```

output:

```
from myMeth!
```

A real practical use for this would be, overriding a public known method in that hidden class. You can implement a public method in a hidden class, so the world can call your public method (public implementation rather) without the class being exposed. For example the public method of the Object class is overridden here by DefClass:

PubClass.java

```
package p1;

class DefClass{
    public String toString(){
        return "DefClass here. Trying to explain a concept.";
    }
}

public class PubClass extends DefClass{
    public PubClass(){
        super();
    }
}
```

MainClass.java

```
package p2;

class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        p1.PubClass pub = new p1.PubClass();
        System.out.println(pub.toString());
    }    
}
```

output:

```
DefClass here. Trying to explain a concept.
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `myclass` as `public` then put it in the build path of the class you need to use `myclass`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `myclass` has the default (package-level) access modifier. It should be declared using the `public` access modifier so that it is accessible outside its package. For details, read more about [Controlling Access in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

As a side note, the Java standards require you to capitalize each word in the class name, so you should use `MyClass`. I recommend you the [Java Conventions document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Answer (score 0):

Consider making another public class MyChild with the same package name as MyClass and expose the method from MyChild class

```
public class MyChild extends MyClass {

  public void myTestMethod(){
     super.myTestMethod
   }
```

}

Now in your class where you want to use the method, simply use the instance of MyChild class

```
MyChild m = new MyChild();

m.myTestMethod();
```

Cheers :)